# How to get the Matlab workspace associated with the current Matlab project in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I used the Matlab Compiler Deployment Tool for generate a compile project (generate a dll) that can be referenced in .net.
In the .net project i call functions of Matlab through the dll, and i have results. But i want get the current workspace the Matlab. Is this possible?
Any idea?
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Matlab R2009b.

This is part of the code:

```
Using MatlabPackageNative;

public static MatlabPackageNative.Files Matlab;
Matlab.initialVariables();
Matlab.function1();
Matlab.function2();
```

Comment: Not sure if applies, but it would be better to reorganize your code to avoid using globals and variables defined in the base workspace. That way your functions would be self-contained... Just a thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already the solution, the way is the next:

1. Create a .m file (for example SaveWorskpace.m) con this information:

   ```
   save test.mat
   ```
2. Add SaveWorskpace.m at the project with Matlab Compiler Deployment Tool.
3. Compile the project with Matlab Compiler Deployment Tool
4. Add reference at the c# project
5. Call function SaveWorkspace()
6. Ready, you have variables save in the workspace test.mat